# Alternative to 'stuff' in "with regard to administrative or financial _______."

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you think is a suitable word to use instead of the informal "stuff" here, and is "appropriate" used correctly in this context?

> I will give you the number of the appropriate team that will be able to help you with questions with regard to administrative or financial [stuff].

Comment: Pick the most specific word that covers the subject: it could be something like "procedures" or "problems" or something more general like "issues"/"topics". (There are probably other even more highfalutin options should you want to go that way, e.g. administrativa.)

Comment: Large language models (e.g. ChatGPT) are rightfully criticized for their ability to hallucinate, but they are fantastic for single-word-requests. Just preface your query with "List words that can be replace [blank] in the following sentence:" and it responded with "matters/concerns/issues/topics/queries".

Answer (score 48):

> I will give you the number of the appropriate team that will be able to help you with questions with regard to administrative or financial ***matters***.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matter#:%7E:text=matters%20plural%20%3A%20the%20events%20or,of%20a%20discourse%20or%20writing),

> a subject under consideration
>
> the events or circumstances of a particular situation

---

As for whether *appropriate* is correct: you can use it, but a re-write along the lines of '*I will give you the number of whichever team that would be able to help you...*' sounds better. (to me, at least)

Answer (score 15):

> I will give you the number of the appropriate team that will be able to help you with questions with regard to administrative or financial ***affairs***.

---

> *affairs*, [plural]: commercial, professional, public, or personal business [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affair)
>
> a situation or subject that is being dealt with or considered [(Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/affair)

Answer (score 13):

I would personally go with *matters*, but sometimes you can use ***issues***.

> I will give you the number of the appropriate team that will be able to help you with questions with regard to administrative or financial ***issues***.

An *issue* is

> a subject or problem that people are thinking and talking about:
>
> - environmental/ethical/personal issues ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issue))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issue) also defines it as

> CONCERN, PROBLEM

So while *matters* is nice and neutral, ***issue*** has something more, let's say, *alarming* about it, something that *needs to be resolved*.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is [**concerns**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concern): (Merriam-Webster)

> 3 a : matter for consideration
>
> *Immigration had become a concern to Congress.*

Answer (score 3):

I think the suitable substitute word for 'stuff' is 'matter' because matter refers to a subject under consideration. For example, "Could I talk to you about a personal matter?". Example is taken from [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matter).

Also, based on my personal experience, I believe a better word for "appropriate" is "relevant."

Answer (score 2):

I think that the word "appropriate" is not incorrect, but it should be omitted as unnecessary duplication.
The statement that the team "will be able to help" implies that it is the appropriate team, so no information is added by explicitly using the word.

Comment: What about the main part of the question?

Comment: This is my first post here. As there were two parts to the question, I answered them separately. You seem to be implying that this was not correct procedure?

Comment: You should put them together and delete one of them- separate answers are, it seems, only merited when you have separate _words_ to suggest. (You have one word and then address the other part)

Comment: Thank you Heartspring

Answer (score 1):

As other contributors have shown, there are a lot of possible alternatives to "stuff". As none of them are all-inclusive, I would suggest that a more elegant solution is to avoid using "stuff" and the alternatives - by rewording the sentence. e.g.

> I will give you the number of the team that will be able to help you with administrative or financial questions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the precise nature of the stuff, you may want *details*.

> information about someone or something [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/details)

This would, of course, suggest that the team was to help the person being addressed elaborate the central matter.

Answer (score -1):

> **duty** (noun)
> 2a : obligatory tasks, conduct, service, or functions that arise from one's position
> *"performs a variety of administrative duties"*
> (from Merriam-Webster)

For the particular sentence in question, we are talking about tasks and functions relating to the work at an employee's current role (i.e. their position).  Therefore it is very natural to talk about the specific "administrative duties" of the role or its "financial duties".

> I will give you the number of the appropriate team that will be able to help you with questions [regarding] administrative or financial **duties**.